# Is there a solution to this invalid key error for google maps api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I'm building an app using React.js that uses the google maps api.  But I keep getting an Invalid Key error even though the api key is correct.

I have stored my API key in a .env file and and passed it to the google maps URL along with the actual URL. But I still get an error. When I add the URL and API key together without trying to store it in a .env file the map loads just fine. I've also tried storing the API key in a variable but that won't work either.

My code is as follows:

```
function Run() {
    return (
        <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
        <WrappedMap 
         googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY}&callback=initMap`}
         loadingElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
         containerElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
         mapElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
         />
        </div>
    )
}
```

With the above code the map renders at first but then display error message that something went wrong.  I then check my console and I see the Invalid Key error and Invalid Key Map error.  Any solutions to this problem are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY)` and `console.log(\`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY}&callback=initMap\`)` to check the key is coming in correctly and the url is formatting correcly?

Comment: Ok yea I did that and I'm getting back undefined. So I'm not sure why that is if the syntax looks correct to me.

Comment: Using a process.env file with a React app (or any client-run app) is not straightforward. See [link] (https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5) for more info.